# Find the value of the following limit: $\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_x^{x^2} \sin(\frac1t)\cos(\frac1t)dt$

Tags: calculus

Find the value of the following limit: $\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_x^{x^2} \sin(\frac1t)\cos(\frac1t)dt$ , or show that it does not exist.

It is impossible to use the Newton-Leibniz formula since this does not have an elementary antiderivative, I tried to split the integral using additivity:
$\int_x^{x^2} \sin(\frac1t)\cos(\frac1t)dt=\int_1^{x^2} \sin(\frac1t)\cos(\frac1t)dt-\int_1^{x} \sin(\frac1t)\cos(\frac1t)dt$

Using convergence tests, I concluded that the two integrals in the difference are divergent (when $x \to \infty$), so I cannot say anything about the limit of their difference when $x \to \infty$. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Hint: the integrand is asymptotic to $1/t$, the integrand to $\ln x$, so...

Comment: How to justify it more precisely?

Comment: Something as simple as $\sin(1/t) \ge 1/(2t)$ and $\cos(1/t) \ge 1/2$ for large enough $t$ is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For small values of $y>0$, $\sin y\gt y/2$ and $\cos y\gt 1/2$. The second one is true for $y<\pi/3$. The first one is also true in the $(0,\pi/3)$ range. One cal look at $\sin y-\frac y2$. At $y=0$ $\sin 0 - 0=0$. The derivative is $\cos y-1/2$, which is positive for $y\in (0,\pi/3)$. Then, for $x>3/\pi$, $$\int_x^{x^2}\sin(1/t)\cos(1/t) dt>\int_x^{x^2}\frac1{2t}\frac12dt$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

Using $\sin x\ge \frac{2}{\pi} x$ for $x\in[0,\pi/2]$ one has
$$\int_x^{x^2} \sin(\frac1t)\cos(\frac1t)dt=\frac12\int_x^{x^2} \sin(\frac2t)dt\ge\int_{x}^{{x^2}} \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{dt}{t}=\frac2\pi\ln x $$
and hence
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_x^{x^2} \sin(\frac1t)\cos(\frac1t)dt=\infty.$$